# TabLayout inferior sin AppToolbar

Tags: android, xml, fragment

como andan?
No se como configurar mi tablayout a la parte inferior de mi pantalla
Estoy usando fragments y mi vista principal es un CoordinatorLayout.
La idea del `TabLayout` es usarlo sin el `Toolbar`.
Este es mi codigo XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".SendHelp">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

y en mi OnCreate tengo

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_help);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
}
```

La idea de la vista seria algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basado en tu layout original, la forma de realizar esto es sencilla, en lugar de un `CoordinatorLayout` que en realidad no es necesario usa el `ConstraintLayout`. Actualmente es importante conocer como funciona el `ConstraintLayout` el cual nos permitirá crear complejos layouts sin realizar carga en el procesador.

Para posicionar en la parte inferior el `TabLayout` usa la propiedad

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

de esta forma posicionarías el `TabLayout`en la parte inferior del contenedor padre.

Este sería el layout con el cambio :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".SendHelp">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Este sería el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: Muchas gracias!, me resulto muy practica esta solucion.
Simple y concisa :D

Comment: Excelente @LucasG , saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Yo te recomendaría usar el elemento `BottomNavigationView` de la siguiente manera, en `fragment_vantispeople.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".fragments.FragmentVantisPeople"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_vantispeople"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/colores_boton"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/colores_boton"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:id="@+id/btn_vantispeople"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:menu="@menu/vantispeople_menu"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

en tu `FragmentVantisPeople.java`:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentVantisPeople extends Fragment {
    //index para los fragments
    private static final String TAG_FRAGMENT_A  = "a";    
    private static final String TAG_FRAGMENT_B  = "b";
    private static final String TAG_FRAGMENT_C  = "c";
    private static final String TAG_FRAGMENT_D  = "d";
    private static final String TAG_FRAGMENT_E  = "e";
    private static String CURRENT_TAG           = TAG_FRAGMENT_A;
    public  static int navItemIndex              = 0;
    private BottomNavigationView bnv;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private View view;

    public  FragmentVantisPeople() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vantispeople, container, false);


        bnv             = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_vantispeople);
        mHandler        = new Handler();
        inicializarMenu();
        //Carga el primer fragment por defecto index 0
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            navItemIndex = 0;
            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_PERFIL;
            actualizarFragment();
        }

        return view;
    }

    private void inicializarMenu() { bnv.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                //Se enlazan los index con su repectivo menú
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.btn_a:
                        navItemIndex    = 0;
                        CURRENT_TAG     = TAG_FRAGMENT_A;
                        break;
                    case R.id.btn_b:
                        navItemIndex    = 1;
                        CURRENT_TAG     = TAG_FRAGMENT_B;
                        break;
                    case R.id.btn_c:
                        navItemIndex    = 2;
                        CURRENT_TAG     = TAG_FRAGMENT_C;
                        break;
                    case R.id.btn_d:
                        navItemIndex    = 3;
                        CURRENT_TAG     = TAG_FRAGMENT_D;
                        break;
                    case R.id.btn_e:
                        navItemIndex    = 4;
                        CURRENT_TAG     = TAG_FRAGMENT_E;
                        break;
                    default:
                        navItemIndex    = 0;
                }
                actualizarFragment();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void actualizarFragment() {
        Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Actualizar el fragment correspondiente en el "contenedor"
                Fragment fragment = obtenerFragmentActual();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in,
                        R.anim.fade_out);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_vantispeople, fragment,CURRENT_TAG);
                fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
        };
        if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
            mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
        }
    }
    private Fragment obtenerFragmentActual() {
        switch (navItemIndex) {
            case 0:
                return new FragmentA();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentB();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentC();
            case 3:
                return new FragmentD();
            case 4:
                return new FragmentE();
            default:
                return new FragmentA();
        }
    }
}
```

Dirígete a res > menu y crea el archivo `vantispeople_menu.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/btn_a"
        android:title="Fragment A"
        android:icon="@drawable/img_a" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/btn_b"
        android:title="Fragment B"
        android:icon="@drawable/img_b"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/btn_c"
        android:title="Fragment C"
        android:icon="@drawable/img_c"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/btn_d"
        android:title="Fragment D"
        android:icon="@drawable/img_d"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/btn_e"
        android:title="Fragment E"
        android:icon="@drawable/img_e"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder,lo voy a tener muy encuenta!